# java.lang.NullPointerException with JMenu and JMenuBar

Tags: java, jmenu

I have a JMenuBar that has one menu and three `JRadioButtonMenuItems`:

```
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
JRadioButtonMenuItem rbMenuItem;
```

I declare it:

```
    menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
   ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("A radio button menu item");
rbMenuItem.setSelected(true);

group.add(rbMenuItem);
menu.add(rbMenuItem);
menuBar.add(menu);
```

and I set it as the menu bar:

```
this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

I run the file and it gives me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at geometry.tools.main.RectangleFrame.<init>(RectangleFrame.java:47)
    at geometry.tools.main.RectangleFrame.main(RectangleFrame.java:95)
Java Result: 1
```

Line 47 is:

```
menuBar.add(menu);
```

and line 95 is:

```
 RectangleFrame thr = new RectangleFrame();
```

in the:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    RectangleFrame thr = new RectangleFrame();
}
```

I don't really understand why. I haven't specified any value as `null` so I don't see why I get this error.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`menuBar` is not initialized

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
```

Comment: @DLJ In java any un-initialized reference throws NPE, if tried to access it. its not specific to `JMenuBar`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of your menubar.

`JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar()`